# If circular type definitions are valid

Tags: logic, type-theory

I am [confused](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104093/if-you-can-have-cyclic-base-types-or-if-they-need-to-be-infinite-types) about type hierarchies in programming languages, which seem to be limited to 2 layers for some reason.

This got me wondering if [circular reasoning](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-circular-reasoning-a-logical-fallacy) in regards to types is a logical fallacy or if something is wrong with it, and what exactly is wrong with it if so.

For example, at the base level of the type hierarchy it seems like this....

> - An *Object* is an instanceof a *Class*.
> - A *Class* is an instanceof an *Object*.

So

```
Object < Class
Class < Object
```

I'm wondering if there are mathematically any problems with this. I don't really know what they would be, but if circular reasoning is a logical fallacy, maybe there is something to it. That's why in that linked question I was wondering about [infinite types and type universes](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html).

But perhaps with this set of base definitions proofs using these things somehow become invalid or something, I'm not sure what kind of problems this might bring.

I will now explain more of what I mean by "object" and "class"....

An **object** is an *instance* of a class. That is, a class defines *general properties* of a group or collection of things, these things which we name "objects". So any collection of stuff that shares a common set of properties can be said to be a collection of "objects".

A **class** is that general model of a collection of things we are calling "objects". The thing is, we can have a *collection of classes*, which together have some general properties. As such we can say we have a *class of classes*. We can do this as much as we want, to have a class of a class of a class, etc. Because we can have a "collection" of classes, and we call the things in a collection "objects", then classes are also "objects". This means that *objects can be classes*, but not that all objects are classes. There can be objects that are not classes. In that, these objects aren't collection of other objects all sharing some general properties. Instead, these objects have other properties not really relevant here.

This is a *mathematical problem* because I would like to see if properly formulating this system will allow you to *prove* some sort of logical statements regarding the types and type instances. I have looked at [Coq](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT) but haven't really understood how they formulated the [Infinite Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html) ([type universes](http://www2.math.uu.se/~palmgren/universe.pdf)) from [Martin-Löf's Type Theory](https://archive-pml.github.io/martin-lof/pdfs/Bibliopolis-Book-retypeset-1984.pdf), and why it's done like that. It doesn't make sense (from as much as I have understood so far from reading about HoTT) what the infinite types / type universes solve, and how it aids in the proving process. I don't see, too, what you really need to prove in a general sense in programming, still having difficulty understanding that. But I feel that if I better understand how types need to work -- so that it results in some sort of "logically valid system" -- that it will make more sense what kind of things you can prove.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a mathematical question here -- it seems more to be about understanding the specification of a particular programming language.

Comment: More specifically, I suspect you're _either_ overloading the word "instanceof" to mean two different relations in your two example, _or_ being sloppy about [use/mention distinctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) when you say "object" and "class", or perhaps both. But it is impossible to tell when you're not explaining more what you mean by your two claims, and in particular what "object" and "class" mean to you here.

Comment: From a mathematical (or theoretical computer science) point of view I suspect you're groping towards something like the [lambda cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube) extended with a new dimension for subtyping. When I was active in theoretical CS research 10-15 years ago, making such an extension behave halfway nice was considered a thorny problem that we had no good solution to -- but I'm not aware what progress has been made since then.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is mathematical because I am coming at it from [HoTT](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT) and [Martin-Löf''s Type Theory](https://archive-pml.github.io/martin-lof/pdfs/Bibliopolis-Book-retypeset-1984.pdf) ([type universes](http://www2.math.uu.se/~palmgren/universe.pdf)). I have seen the lambda cube and vaguely know it's related to HoTT, but not sure exactly how it relates otherwise. Relating to mathematics, I am wondering what it takes at the base to be able to _prove_ stuff along the lines of what Coq does, so you need a base that isn't some logically invalid thing.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I updated with the definition of objects and classes.

Comment: Circumstances of circular definitions and circular references can arise in various programming languages.  The problems (of ill-founded defintion) entailed may or may not be caught at compile time.  If they cannot be resolved at runtime, one hopes to get a meaningful error message then.  I've looked over your post and the closest I see you getting to asking a question is where you state early on that you are "wondering if circular reasoning in regards to types is a logical fallacy" or something else.  Is that your Question?  It doesn't strike me as amenable to mathematical reasoning.

Comment: Your added explanation sounds like it is simply describing a plain old _set theory with urelements_, except you're calling sets "classes" (but many of the people involved with inventing set theory did so too).

Comment: In most programming languages the terms _class_ and _object_ are defined in a much more restricted sense than you are defining them. A collection of objects in that context is _not_ just any "collection of stuff that shares a common set of properties".

Comment: i might well be misunderstanding what you're after, but are you already aware of the concepts of [inductive-inductive types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inductive-inductive+type) and [metaobject protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaobject)? Also, with regards to your comment that "[i]t doesn't make sense ... what the infinite types / type universes solve": they're to deal with manifestations of Russell's paradox, such as [Girard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_U#Girard's_paradox).